# There's a quadruple circle

Tags: singular

[image]

[image]

[image]

A picture above two pictures shows a quadruple circle. Can I describe the two picture below the first picture 'there's half of a quadruple circle'?

---

this picture is additional to the original post.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I describe the two picture below the first picture 'there's half
> of a quadruple circle'?

We don't use quadruple in that way. If someone asked me to a draw a quadruple circle, I would probably draw the following:

[image]

The reason is that you are talking about "a" circle. "The indefinite article "a" means "one".  Therefore I would imagine one circle with perhaps different colours.

If you really want to use mathematical terminology, you could describe your first two pictures as ***quadruplet***s.

Picture 1. A quadruplet of circles

Picture 2. A quadruplet of half-circles

Picture 3. A duplet of circles

Non-mathematicians would probably have to ask what you meant, especially if you did not provide a diagram.

> Definition of **quadruplet**
>  1: a combination of four of a
> kind
>  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quadruplet

---

Comment: Then, to say 'There's half of it', can I erase the whole of green and red circle, or erase a half of the whole circle?

Comment: @yourfriend - If you said "There's half of a quadruple circle" to me, I would assume a four-coloured semi-circle.  I think it would help if you explained the reasons for asking. The word "quadruple" is mostly used as an indication of multiplication. For example, "John's income is quadruple (four times) what it was ten years ago."

Comment: Thank you, I got it.

Comment: I figured out quadruple can be a predeterminer!

Comment: Here's something about that, *"Core Members and Marginal Members
"The special quantifiers all, both, and half are the core members of the class of predeterminers. **Other fractions and multiples (twice, thrice, three times, etc.) are marginal members**. This set of quantifying elements is distinct from ordinary quantifiers such as many, some, much, and the cardinal and ordinal numerals."*  https://www.thoughtco.com/predeterminer-grammar-1691524  -  I'm not sure why they are described as marginal. I've never thought about it before.  Maybe you can tell me!!!

Comment: "duplet"? What's wrong with "pair"? I have never seen the word "duplet" in 4 decades of academic reading.

Comment: @Prime Mover - There's nothing wrong with "pair" in normal discourse. However, for me it carries overtones of similarity or even equivalence.  In mathematical terms, a duplet of circles could apply to two different circles, e.g. One large green circle and one small red circle. In conversation, I would think of a pair as identical (e.g. a pair of circular earrings of the same size and material).  In mathematics, one defines terms before using them - the more rigorous the definition the better.

Comment: @Prime Mover  - P.S.  Here are some examples from Google Scholar https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=mathematics+duplet&btnG=

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica It seems in this general context that it may be a non-British introduction to the English language. My own googling suggests that it has 2 specialised applications: in music, and in electron physics. (I recognise the word now.) But it is so rare as for it to be obscure to see it applied to the general terminology. In my own modest mathematical accomplishments I have used the term "ordered pair" if the ordering is important, and "doubleton" for a set containing 2 elements. The difference or not of the elements is inconsequential.

Comment: @Prime Mover - I don't have an axe to grind about this. My purpose was to help with the understanding of English. I repeated "-plet", merely for the sake of consistency of language.  The problem for me is that the OP has declined to specify the purpose of their query. I was trying to make my answer as general as possible. In the population at large, the only common use of "quadruplet" is in the description of children. If that were the context, then the best analog would not be "pair" or "doubleton", it would be "twin". Once we leave normal context behind, we need to choose & define our terms.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica My own take on this is that any instance of the "quad-" word in any of its incarnations is pointless obfuscation, unless there is a *specific need* to specify their order, in which case you would use "ordered quadruple" (at least, in the language I speak and write). If all you're doing is showing a row of badly-drawn circles, then "four circles" is completely adequate.

Comment: @Prime Mover - I don't disagree about saying "four," except that it does not answer the OP's question as asked. The problem with using any of *pair, brace, doubleton, twin, couple, duo, dyad, twosome,  etc*. is that they are highly context-dependent and evoke extra meanings that may not be required. In a conversation about, triplets, quadruplets, quintuplets, etc. It seems easier to use another word ending in "-plet" and to indicate how many by prepending the Latin version of the number.

Comment: I added a more appropriate picture.

Comment: That is a picture of four circles inside a bigger circle. That makes a total of five circles. At this point we need to be crystal clear about what you are asking and why. Do have a purpose in mind - perhaps to do some mathematics? Or are you simply asking about the usage of the word "quadruplet" in everyday conversational English?

Comment: I intended the latter, but I'm also fond of the former.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong picture. Wait.

Comment: In general conversation, the only meaning that most people will understand is that a quadruplet is one of four children born from the same pregnancy. In terms of maths, it is simply a matter of making a clear definition and sticking to it rigorously. Apart from that I suggest reading the dictionary definitions carefully and searching, say, Google Books for various usages.  https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=quadruplet

Answer (score 3):

No

In the first picture there are four circles.  It isn't "a quadruple circle". A "quadruple circle" could be a circle consisting of four parts, each part being a complete circle. Yours isn't a four-part-circle. It is a picture of four circles.

In the second picture there are four semicircles or four half-circles,

In the third picture there are two circles.

Please don't try to make this confusing.  Try to make it clear for the person you are talking to.

For this you shouldn't use "a quadruple circle", as a verb "I quadrupled a circle". Nor is "quadruplet of circles" a good way to say it.  Numbers are the best way to say how many there are:

> There are four circles.

Comment: Why is 'a quadruple circle' wrong?

Comment: A "quadruple circle" is a circle consisting of four part.  Your picture isn't a picture of a circle consisting of four part.  It is four circles. Moreover, why use "quadruple" which is technically wrong and confusing instead of the simple word "four"

Comment: I found the dictionary, and I figured out I got to say quadruple a circle, not a quadruple circle.

Comment: @yourfriend "Quadruple a circle" does not sound remotely correct to an English native. If you *have* to use the "quadruple" word, use "a *quadruplet* of circles". But in fact it is questionable that there is a need for such a long word in the first place. What is wrong with just "four circles"?

Comment: I try to make a sentence to memorize a new word.

Comment: Okay,  the dictionary will give you some better sentences to use to learn it:  "I will have the quadruple chocolate desert" (four types of chocolate in one desert). "There was a quadruple murder last night" (four people killed at the same time)